# Unit testing Math.min()

Tags: java, unit-testing

I don't understand how the following unit test (from my textbook) adequately tests Java's `Math.min()` method:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
   This app tests the method min of the class Math.
*/
public class MathTester
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        final int VECTOR_SIZE = 100;

        Random random = new Random();
        boolean pass = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE && pass; i++)
        {
            int a = random.nextInt();
            int b = random.nextInt();
            double min = Math.min(a, b);
            if (a < min || b < min && (a != min && b != min))
            {
                System.out.print("The method failed the test case: ");
                System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
                pass = false;
            }
        }
        if (pass)
        {
            System.out.println("The method passed all test cases");
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose `a == 5`, `b == 3`, and `min == 2`. This should generate a failure because `Math.min()` is supposed to return the lesser of its arguments (and 2 is not an argument). Yet it seems to me the test would (wrongly) pass this case because `a` and `b` are both greater than 2, therefore the `if` block, which contains the fail code, would not execute.

Comment: Looks like it is a typo: it should be `a < min || b < min || (a != min && b != min)`.

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: That said, it doesn't adequately test Math.min. If Math.min() always returned a and you were unlucky enough to have the random a always smaller than the random b, the test wouldn't see the error. Unit tests should generally not use random numbers. Just test with 0 and 1, then 1 and 0, then 1 and 1, and you're almost sure to have covered to probable bugs in the implementation, and all the possible cases. The test will also be much simpler, and have much less chance to contain a bug.

Comment: @JBNizet: Negative values should also be tested. It also is only testing the int overload of Math.min.

Comment: @Chill The test if for Math.min(int, int). You could test for negative numbers, but it wouldn't add much: there is no reason for Math.min to treat them differently from positive numbers, unless the implementation is extremely convoluted.

Comment: @JBNizet How is it that my university professor (who wrote this text) isn't aware of this?

Comment: University professors often don't have professional experience in the field, sometimes are even stuck years or decades in the past. I've yet to see people learn how to cleanly develop quality software in a university. Very unfortunate, but common.

Comment: For demonstration? It is not your responsibility to unit test the JVM.

Comment: @JBNizet: Noticed that it was int after posting my comment. The whole point of testing is to verify behavior. Don't assume the implementation is correct and that there won't be regressions just because it seems straightforward. Sure this is a simple example, but I would still make negatives and other boundaries tested (Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE perhaps). Maybe the implementation uses some clever bit logic that is correct except for the min value. Who knows? That's why the test helps give confidence.

Comment: Most teachers I've met are far less aware of good practices, conventions and state of the art than professional software developers. I don't know if your teacher is aware of it or not (maybe he'll come to that later), but no developer would use a main method with text written to the console to implement a test. Developers would use JUnit or TestNG, for example.

Comment: @Chill I agree in general, except tests aren't proofs. I generally write tests for the code I wrote, and thus know the corner-cases. Even if I didn't wrote Math.min(), when I test it, I try to imagine what reasonable mistake the developer could have made. And I can think of three: always return a, always return b, or using > instead of <.